# SAS PROC TABULATE: Colour based on cell value

Tags: sas

I have two cross-tabs being output in SAS: one for Time0 and one for Time1. I am interesting in comparing the change in values in each of the cells in the first crosstab with those in second.

Is there a clever way to change the background colour of a cell based on a comparison with an equivalent cell in another cross-tab? If not, and I create a variable with the change in the variable between Time0 and Time1, how can I change the cell colour of the crosstab depending on whether a value is positive or negative? Is it possible to put a colour gradient in increments of 5% if the cell contains a percentage change?

I have some sample data as follows:

```
data have;
    input username $  betdate : datetime. stake;
    dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
    format betdate DATETIME.;
    format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
    datalines; 
    player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 90
    player1 04NOV2008:09:03:44 30
    player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 120
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:00 50
    player1 05NOV2008:09:05:00 30
    player1 05NOV2008:09:00:05 20
    player2 09NOV2008:10:05:10 10
    player2 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35
    player1 15NOV2008:15:05:33 35
    run;

proc sort data=have; by username betdate; run;

data have;
    set have;
    by username dateOnly betdate;   
    retain eventTime;
    if first.username then eventTime = 0;
    if first.betdate then eventTime + 1;
run;

proc sql;
    create table playerStats as 
    select 
    distinct username,
    (select distinct avg(stake) from have where username = main.username and eventTime <= 1) format comma10.2 as bet1AvgStake,
    (select distinct avg(stake) from have where username = main.username and eventTime <= 2) format comma10.2 as bet2AvgStake,
    (select distinct avg(stake) from have where username = main.username and eventTime <= 3) format comma10.2 as bet3AvgStake
    from have main;
quit;

Proc rank data=playerStats ties=mean out=customerStats groups=2;
    var     bet1AvgStake bet2AvgStake;
    ranks   bet1AvgStakeRank bet2AvgStakeRank;
run;

PROC TABULATE DATA=customerStats NOSEPS;
    VAR bet1AvgStake bet2AvgStake;
    class bet1AvgStakeRank;
    TABLE bet1AvgStakeRank, bet1AvgStake*(N Mean);
    TABLE bet1AvgStakeRank, bet2AvgStake*(N Mean);
RUN;
```

I would like to see a red cell when the value in each cell in the second crosstab is lower than the equivalent cell in the first and a green cell when the value is higher.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: What about doing it with PROC REPORT?  Its easy to add a compute block to do this.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't read it quite clearly.  I think to do that, you would have to use proc tabulate to create an output dataset, do the comparison there (making some sort of flag variable on what you want to highlight) and then print it out with proc report and do your shading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do all that in a single proc, but you certainly can do part 2 if I understand properly.  It's called "Traffic Lighting" more generally, to help with googling for more detailed information; for example, [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/085-29.pdf) has some examples of how to do so.

Generally, the concept is that you create a format, the label of which is a color:

```
proc format; 
 value betfmt 
    low - -5= 'red' 
    -5 >-> 0 = 'lightred'
    0 - 5 ='lightgreen'
     5 >- high = 'green'; *or hex values like 'cxFF0099';
quit;
```

Then use that format in the proc tabulate:

```
proc tabulate data=yourdata;
var bets;
tables bets/style=[background=betfmt.];
run;
```

It does need to be based on the current cell, though; you can't calculate based on another cell without using PROC REPORT.